# Chart Data Not Updating for Both Graphs?

Tags: chart.js

I have two bar graphs that get updated with a function which is called whenever I add an input into the dataset.

```
function updateChartData(chart, dataLabels, dataNumbers) {
    chart.data.labels = dataLabels;
    chart.data.datasets[0].data = dataNumbers;
    chart.update();
}
```

Even though both graph's labels are being updated, only one is updating the bars. If I keep adding inputs up to 9 values it'll start updating the bars thereon after.

I tried isolating the graph that's having problems by deleting the second chart but didn't fix. I've tried to use the same datasets for both graphs but it ended up doing this weird thing where if i add an input, the first graph would lag the second graph. For example:

*add 1 input to dataset-

first chart shows nothing, second chart shows 1 input

*add 1 more input to dataset-

first chart shows 1 input, second chart shows 2 inputs.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually found the solution but couldn't find it before posting this. The problem was that the API I got the data from was giving me strings of numbers with ","s. Coincidentally  the 9th input I was adding in was less than 1,000 so it could turn the number such as 999 into a number.